# Загрузка файлов через админку

Tags: django

Добрый день, имеется модель вида

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(..)
    info = models.TextField(..)
```

т.е. обычное изображение с каким-то описанием. Заливка производится через админку. Заливать поштучно - не удобно. Можно ли как-то запилить модель и заливать через админку сразу по несколько изображений, на примере инлайнов? Желательно без подключения сторонних js-библиотек :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну сделайте еще одну модель, типа ImageSet, в Image добавьте ForeignKey на неё, и подключив Inline, - можете заливать сразу кучу картинок.

Comment: Это уже приделывание костыля, саааамый крайный вариант) Нужно элегантное решение :)

Comment: Ничего хитрее не придумал, сделаю как Вы предложили :)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что лучше всего использовать все-таки библиотеки, т.к они написаны хорошо и имеют хорошее время выполнения!
 Вот что вам понадобится

1. jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin v1.31 [тута](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) (сам плагин)
2. Query Form Plugin v2.18 [тута](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) (Плагин для ajax работы с формами.)
3. jQuery BlockUI Plugin v2.14 [тута](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) (для ошибок)
4. ну JQuery найдете сами))

Апишки довольно простые, написать не сложно)
Как и что делать дальше можно прочитать вот [тута](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/50223/)

Comment: Спасибо, что не поленились указать все источники, но я написал, что желательно без подключения стороннего js :) Я уж лучше сделаю костыль с доп. моделью...

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этой книге **"Django Разработка веб-приложений на Python"**, в главе - создание галереи, там подробно всё описано и там как рас применяется метод загрузки одновременно нескольких картинок.

Качайте книгу и за 10 минут разберётесь с первоисточника.

Comment: За наводку конечно спасибо, да только там используется принцип, описанный товарищем @Тарас.

Comment: Понял, тогда ему +1. Отметите верное решение, если будет, может когда пригодится.

Comment: Конечно отмечу, если его найдём... Пока что предложенные варианты не очень подходят.